# How do i convert this array of string to array of dict with values defined by =

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this array:

```
['clid=1 cid=174 client_database_id=246 client_nickname=Music\\sBot client_type=0', 'clid=2 cid=181 client_database_id=247 client_nickname=xxx client_type=0', 'clid=5 cid=174 client_database_id=140 client_nickname=xxx client_type=0', 'clid=6 cid=174 client_database_id=158 client_nickname=xxx client_type=0', 'clid=7 cid=174 client_database_id=218 client_nickname=xxx client_type=0', 'clid=11 cid=174 client_database_id=202 client_nickname=xxx client_type=0']
```

And i want to convert to something like this

```
[{"clid": 1,
"cid": 174,
"client_database_id": 246,
"client_nickname": "Music\\sBot"
"client_type":0},
{"clid": 2,
"cid": 181,
"client_database_id": 247,
"client_nickname": "xxx"
"client_type":0}, {...}
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), splitting every item by space and splitting every pair by `=` as well as passing the pairs to the [`dict()` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) for dictionary creation:

```
In [2]: processed_list = [dict(pair.split('=') for pair in item.split(' ')) 
                          for item in your_list]
In[3]: processed_list
Out[3]: 
[{'cid': '174',
  'clid': '1',
  'client_database_id': '246',
  'client_nickname': 'Music\\sBot',
  'client_type': '0'},
 ...
 {'cid': '174',
  'clid': '11',
  'client_database_id': '202',
  'client_nickname': 'xxx',
  'client_type': '0'}]
```

where `your_list` is your list.

---

If you'd like to further convert the ids and client_type to integers, there could be multiple ways to do that - we could, for instance, convert to `int()` entries for keys which end with `id` or `type`:

```
processed_list = [{key: (int(value) if key.endswith(('id', 'type')) else value) 
                   for key, value in entry.items()} 
                  for entry in processed_list]
```

Comment: Unlike the example answer, the integer values are strings.

Comment: The `' '` in the split is redundant, because it splits on whitespace by default.

Comment: @gilch as well as newlines and tabs, I wanted to be explicit and split by space.